# split dataframe by group into similar-sized chunks

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(x=rep(c('A','B'), times=c(5,15)), y=1:20)
```

I'm trying to split `df` into chunks of similar size with the constraint that each group in `x` must also be represented and split equally across `n` splits. For example if `n = 3`:

```
$`1`
   x  y
1  A  1
2  A  2
3  B  6
4  B  7
5  B  8
6  B  9
7  B 10

$`2`
   x  y
1  A  3
2  A  4
3  B 11
4  B 12
5  B 13
6  B 14
7  B 15

$`3`
   x  y
1  A  5
2  B 16
3  B 17
4  B 18
5  B 19
6  B 20
```

For n=3, group `A` can be divided into chunks of [2,2,1], whereas group `B` can be divided into chunks of [5,5,5]

I tried:

```
n = 3
df %>% group_by(x) %>% split(., cut(seq_along(.), n, labels = FALSE))
```

but this creates only two splits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are along the right lines using `cut`. Just make sure that you have `n + 1` breaks for each group in  `x`, which are split according to the proportion that their row number represents of the total group. Here's a full reprex:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x=rep(c('A','B'), times=c(5,15)), y=1:20)

n <- 3

df %>%
  mutate(group = cut((row_number() - 1)/n(), 
                     breaks = seq(0, 1, length = n + 1), 
                     labels = seq(n),
                     include.lowest = TRUE,
                     right = FALSE),
         .by = x) %>%
  {split(.[-3], .[3])}
#> $`1`
#>    x  y
#> 1  A  1
#> 2  A  2
#> 6  B  6
#> 7  B  7
#> 8  B  8
#> 9  B  9
#> 10 B 10
#> 
#> $`2`
#>    x  y
#> 3  A  3
#> 4  A  4
#> 11 B 11
#> 12 B 12
#> 13 B 13
#> 14 B 14
#> 15 B 15
#> 
#> $`3`
#>    x  y
#> 5  A  5
#> 16 B 16
#> 17 B 17
#> 18 B 18
#> 19 B 19
#> 20 B 20
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't seem to be getting the same output as you when I use my example data frame. Is it working with you?

Comment: @HappyPy using your exact data frame and the exact code above gives the exact output demonstrated on my machine. I have changed to a reprex to demonstrate this. Do you get a different result?

Comment: Thanks for checking. Yes, I'm getting a different output, when I copy-paste your code into RStudio... Very strange. This is happening even in a new session.

Comment: @HappyPy: In case your output contains a `.by` column you are using an older dplyr version that doesn't support the `.by` argument in  `mutate`. You'd need to use `group_by(x)` instead.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In base R we can `split` indices of the respective *x* values at a `seq_len` where we `rep`eat `each` element by the `ceiling` of their length divided by the desired `n`. If the values are unequal we'll get warned, which we may switch off, though, in this case.

```
> f <- \(df, g='x', n=3) {
+   s1 <- lapply(unique(df[[g]]), \(z){
+                w <- which(df[[g]] == z)
+                split(df[w, ], rep(seq_len(n), each=ceiling(length(w)/n)))
+                }) |> suppressWarnings()
+   do.call(Map, c(rbind, s1))
+ }
> f(df)
$`1`
   x  y
1  A  1
2  A  2
6  B  6
7  B  7
8  B  8
9  B  9
10 B 10

$`2`
   x  y
3  A  3
4  A  4
11 B 11
12 B 12
13 B 13
14 B 14
15 B 15

$`3`
   x  y
5  A  5
16 B 16
17 B 17
18 B 18
19 B 19
20 B 20
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(x = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
    y = 1:20), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Answer (score 2):

When splitting datasets I like to work with nested `data.frames` in the tidyverse. Here is one way to split your data using the modulo operator `%%`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  mutate(split = row_number() %% 3,
         .by = x) |> # for older dplyr versions use `group_by(x)` before `mutate` instead of `.by`
  nest_by(split) 

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Rowwise:  split
#>   split               data
#>   <dbl> <list<tibble[,2]>>
#> 1     0            [6 × 2]
#> 2     1            [7 × 2]
#> 3     2            [7 × 2]
```

If you prefer to have the smaller dataset at the end, we can use `mutate(split = (row_number() -1) %% 3)` instead.

Data from OP

```
df <- data.frame(x=rep(c('A','B'), times=c(5,15)), y=1:20)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>